# Why does i become negative?

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

I'm quite new to this and I ran into this problem where I'm supposed to find the value for i in this circuit using superposition. In the short circuit case when only the current source is active I got that i = 5/3 A through current division. In the open circuit case where only the voltage source remains active I got i = 2/5 A. Putting these two together gives i = 31/15 ≈ 2.1 A.

The problem is that the current in the short circuit case should be i = -5/3 A. I can't figure out why this is or how I'm supposed see it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Draw the arrow upwards. Will it become positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the short circuit case when only the current source is active I got that i=5/3 A

It should be -5/3 A. Mind the direction:

[image]

> In the open circuit case where only the voltage source remains active I got i=2/5 A.

Correct, from 12 / 30.

> The problem is that the current in the short circuit case should be i=-5/3 A

Indeed! The current **i** is negative:

[image]